# Is there any way we can use react's new context api with react-redux package?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-context

My app used redux for state management, now I need some data from a reducer and some actions which update that data to pass to deeply nested component. Is there any way we can use react's new context API with the react-redux package?

Comment: why not use redux to do the same ? you need to just connect the component. dosent matter how deep

Comment: you technically can, but just use redux to remove the overhead of maintaining both functionalities. as the other commenter has said, it doesn't matter how deep. You can just use ```connect``` HOC to the deepest component and access your redux data/store from that.